# How can I fade the container and not the Div's inside of it, such as images or test or nav bar's?

Tags: css

I am having the worst time getting the text and images and nav bar inside of the container not to take on the parent div attribute.  My container div is currently set over a background image, and the container has an opacity of 60%. However the nav bar that is located in the dv and the text and even images I put in the container are also faded.  I do not wish to fade the content.
I have pseudo class and I have currently tried the z-index trick and I cannot seem to make it work.
I am using dream weaver CS5 also but I am mainly working in script view. I have put my html code and CSS code below.  Can someone please tell me where Im screwing up. Thanks so much

here is the link to the project Im working on.
http://www.vengeancekennels.com/Pages/DesignWork/Websites/1FitGrit/Pages/Home.html

and the link to my style sheet
http://www.vengeancekennels.com/Pages/DesignWork/Websites/1FitGrit/CSS/css1.css

Comment: Yes, child elements will inherit parents opacity. I can't think of anything else than putting an absolute div on top of it with your actual content (transparent background).

Answer (score 0):

you can use an RGBA value for your background color.  the A is for alpha.

a 60% #CCC color is `rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.6)`

note that rgba values are compatible in th following browsers: IE9+, Firefox 3+, Chrome, Safari, and in Opera 10+.